# Root of expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have the following expression: $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x))^2] \leq \frac{1}{4k}$, from which I have to show that: $\mathbb{E}[|\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x))|] \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$. But the question is: how? I was first going to take a square root on both sides, however the square root of the expectation does not equal the expectation of the square root (Jensens inequality does not hold since square root is not convex).

Does anybody have a good idea? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the Jensen's inequality to the convex function $f(x)= x^2$ (not $\sqrt{x}$ !)

$$\mathbb{E}^2[|\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x)|] \le \mathbb{E}[(\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x))^2]$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}^2[|\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x)|] \le  \frac{1}{4k}$$
or
$$\mathbb{E}[|\hat{\eta}(x)-\eta(x))|] \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$$